# To use or not to use "to"

Tags: exceptions

Today my co-worker wrote a sentence "We will be able indicate those numbers". I told hım that he should use "to" before "indicate" but he answered that there are some exceptions where you can ıgnore "to" before a verb, and "indicate" is a word that can be an exception. Who ıs rıght?

Comment: It's more accurate to say that 'be able' takes a to-infinitive (I am able to come; she is able to ride a bike; we are / will be able to indicate those numbers), unlike say 'can' or 'must', which take a bare infinitive (I can/must come; she can ride a bike; we can indicate those numbers). But the purpose of ELU is not to address basic questions of grammar.

Comment: He told you a fairy tale. It is to be able to do sth/ to be able to indicate sth. Any dictionary will tell you so. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/able_1?q=able

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Edwin Ashworth, what is the meaning of ELU?

Comment: Maybe your co-worker was confused by the fact that one can say, in everyday English, "We can indicate those numbers." But as Edwin Ashworth notes "We are able" requires "to" before "indicate." ELU = English Language & Usage, this website. Our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) is probably a better fit for questions such as this one.